# Error in Python RotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm using logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler class for logging.

This is how I'm using it.

```
logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logpath, "a", maxBytes=2500000, backupCount=5)
```

The log files are named in this format python.log.x where x=1,2..5

The log files are generated.

The problem I see here is

In python.log.5 log file, I'm seeing this entry

> 2013-06-05 09:58:29,994

In python.log.4 log file, I'm seeing this entry

> 2013-06-05 09:56:29,994

But this is wrong. The entries are seen reversed where the **2013-06-05 09:58:29,994** should be in python.log.4 log file and **2013-06-05 09:56:29,994** should be in python.log.5 log file.

Comment: Agree that doesn't look right. Things to check: 1) reproducible? 2) possible timezone changes 3) try calling `doRollover()` yourself, and force it?

Answer (score 0):

This must be happening because your logging class is being used by multiple processes.